# Lexer to handle lines with line number prefix

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm writing a parser for a language that looks like the following:

```
L00<<identifier>>
L10<<keyword>>
L250<<identifier>>
<<identifier>>
```

That is, each line may or may not start with a line number of the form `Lxxx..` ('L' followed by one or more digits) followed by an identifer or a keyword.  Identifiers are standard `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` and the number of digits following the `L` is not fixed.  Spaces between the line number and following identifer/keyword are optional (and not present in most cases).

My current lexer looks like:

```
// Parser rules
commands      : command*;
command       : LINE_NUM? keyword NEWLINE
              | LINE_NUM? IDENTIFIER NEWLINE;
keyword       : KEYWORD_A | KEYWORD_B | ... ;

// Lexer rules
fragment INT  : [0-9]+;
LINE_NUM      : 'L' INT;
KEYWORD_A     : 'someKeyword';
KEYWORD_B     : 'reservedWord';
...
IDENTIFIER    : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

However this results in all lines beginning with a `LINE_NUM` token to be tokenized as `IDENTIFIER`s.

Is there a way to properly tokenize this input using an ANTLR grammar?

Comment: Are there spaces (or a space) between `LINE_NUM` and `IDENTIFIER`?

Comment: @Bart Whitespace between `LINE_NUM` and `IDENTIFIER` is optional.  I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Your sample implies (if it's valid) that an identifier may be optionally preceded by a `LINE_NUM`. The grammar says it's mandatory. Is that right?

Comment: The implied grammar of the sample is the correct behavior. `LINE_NUM` is optional in both cases. I corrected the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a semantic predicate to `IDENTIFIER`:

```
IDENTIFIER
  : {_input.getCharPositionInLine() != 0
      || _input.LA(1) != 'L'
      || !Character.isDigit(_input.LA(2))}?
    [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
  ;
```

You could also avoid semantic predicates by using lexer modes.

```
//
// Default mode is active at the beginning of a line
//

LINE_NUM
  : 'L' [0-9]+ -> pushMode(NotBeginningOfLine)
  ;

KEYWORD_A : 'someKeyword' -> pushMode(NotBeginningOfLine);
KEYWORD_B : 'reservedWord' -> pushMode(NotBeginningOfLine);
IDENTIFIER
  : ( 'L'
    | 'L' [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
    | [a-zA-KM-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
    )
    -> pushMode(NotBeginningOfLine)
  ;
NL : ('\r' '\n'? | '\n');

mode NotBeginningOfLine;

  NotBeginningOfLine_NL : ('\r' '\n'? | '\n') -> type(NL), popMode;
  NotBeginningOfLine_KEYWORD_A : KEYWORD_A -> type(KEYWORD_A);
  NotBeginningOfLine_KEYWORD_B : KEYWORD_B -> type(KEYWORD_B);
  NotBeginningOfLine_IDENTIFIER
    : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]* -> type(IDENTIFIER)
    ;
```

Comment: Both methods look good, thanks!  Any considerations I should take into account that would push me towards one or the other?

Comment: @HarrisonPaine The lexer interpreter isn't able to evaluate semantic predicates, but lexers in combined grammars can't have multiple modes. If it were me, I would use multiple modes and since I always separate my lexers and parsers anyway.

Comment: I implemented the second approach and realized that I was actually facing a different problem, that wasn't evident in the simplified problem. The actual language is nested in another format, which provides a listing of all defined identifiers.  Using the method here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6108549/2483451 I can just tokenize each identifier exactly, saving a lot of headaches.  Still, thanks for answering the question as I posted it; you definitely helped get me out of a stall.

Comment: @280Z28: Is it planned to remove the restraint to disallow multiple lexer modes in combined lexer/parser grammars? Is there any advantage (besides simplicity) from using a combined grammar?

Comment: @Onur I never use combined grammars, because they allow you to accidentally define new literal tokens in parser rules, quickly leading hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: @280Z28: Ok, but besides being able to create hard-to-find bugs, is there any advantage in using combined grammars?