# Optional Prefix in ANTLR parser/lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to use ANTLR4 to parse input strings that are described by a grammar like:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

parse : PREFIX? SEARCH;

PREFIX
  : [0-9]+ ':'
  ;

SEARCH
  : .+ 
  ;
```

e.g. valid input strings include:

```
0: maracujá
apple
3:€53.60
1: 10kg
2:chilli pepper
```

But the `SEARCH` rule always matches the whole string - whether it has a prefix or not.

I understand this is because the ANTLR4 lexer gives preference to the rules that match the longest string. Therefore the `SEARCH` rule matches all input, not giving the `PREFIX` rule a chance.

And the non-greedy version (i.e. `SEARCH : .+? ;`) has the same problem because (as I understand) it's only non-greedy within the rule - and the `SEARCH` rule doesn't have any other parts to constrain it.

If it helps, I could constrain the `SEARCH` text to exclude `':'` but I really would prefer it recognise anything else - unicode characters, symbols, numbers, space etc.

I've read [Lexer to handle lines with line number prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789057/lexer-to-handle-lines-with-line-number-prefix?rq=1) but in that case, the body of the string (after the prefix) is significantly more constrained.

*Note:* `SEARCH` text might have a structure to it - like `€53.00` and `10kg` above (which I'd also like ANTLR4 to parse) or it might just be free text - like `apple`, `maracujá` and `chilli pepper` above. But I've tried to simplify so I can solve the problem of extracting the `PREFIX` first.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to not constrain the `SEARCH` rule, because your grammar would be ambiguous. `0: x 1: y` could be tokenized as either `PREFIX SEARCH PREFIX SEARCH` or `PREFIX SEARCH`.

Comment: in my language `0: x 1: y` would be a `PREFIX` of `0:` and `SEARCH` of `x 1: y` - so there's only ever one `PREFIX` and everything that follows is the `SEARCH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR does lexing before parsing. The lexer prefers long matches and SEARCH tokens match every PREFIX token and even any character appended to it, so your complete line is matched by SEARCH.

To prevent this: Keep the lexer rules disjunct, or at least the tokens should not subsume each other.

```
parse : prefix? search;

search: (WORD | NUMBER)+;

prefix: NUMBER ':';

NUMBER : [0-9]+;
WORD : (~[0-9:])+;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't do what I hoped. When I test with my examples:

`0: maracujá` : `search` matches the whole string. I want `prefix`=`0` and `search`=`maracujá`.


`apple` : OK.


`3:€53.60` : `search` matches the whole string. I expected `prefix`=`3` and `search`=`€53.60`.


`1: 10kg` : OK.


`2:chilli pepper` : `search` matches the whole string. I expected `prefix`=`2` and `search`=`chilli pepper`.

Comment: Exclude the colon `:` from WORD. I corrected the grammar. If you want to allow `:` in your search, adjust the parser rule for search.